# ¿Cómo borrar y reemplazar una imagen de una base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin, php5

quiero borrar imagenes que subo a una base de datos y que se guardan en una carpeta en el disco local. Al darle clic en borrar, la imagen si se elimina la imagen de la tabla, pero en la carpeta sigue estando y el error que me sale es el de permiso denegado en...

Aquí el código para borrar

```html
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['cve_imagen'])){
    $cve_imagen= $_GET['cve_imagen'];
  }
try {
include('conexion.php');

$sql="DELETE FROM imagenes WHERE cve_imagen='$cve_imagen'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
if($resultado){
 unlink("C:/\\wamp64/\\www/\\Proyecto");}
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert ('Archivo Borrado');
window.location='eliminar2.php';
</script>";


} catch(Exception $e){
    $error=$e->getMessage();
  }


 ?>
```

Aquí subo la imagen

```html
<?php
include ('conexion.php');
$nombre      = $_POST['nombre'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
$imagen      = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));

$carpetaPublica  = '/\\uploads/\\'; //
$rutaEnServidor = "C:/\\wamp64/\\www/\\Proyecto$carpetaPublica";

$nombreImagen    = date('Ymd_His').rand().$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$rutaFinalImagenBd = $carpetaPublica.$nombreImagen;

$rutaFinalImagen = $rutaEnServidor.$nombreImagen; 
$pathImagen = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $rutaFinalImagen);

if ($pathImagen) {
 
   $query = "INSERT INTO imagenes(nombre, descripcion, ruta_imagen) VALUES ('$nombre', '$descripcion',  '$rutaFinalImagenBd')";

    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
}{

if($resultado){
 echo"<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert ('El archivo se subio correctamente');
window.location='eliminar.php';
</script>";
 }else {
     echo"<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert ('Error al subir el archivo');
window.location='eliminar.php';
</script>";
  
 }}
 ?>
```

Este es el formulario para actualizar la imagen

```html
$sql="SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE cve_imagen='$cve_imagen'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

} catch(Exception $e){
    $error=$e->getMessage();
  }


 ?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Editar</title>
 <!---  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/editar.css"> -->
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="contenedor">

 <form action="actualizarimg.php" method="get">
       <?php while($registro=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
      <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
          <input type="text" value="<?php echo $registro['nombre']; ?>" name="nombre" id="nombre" >
      <label for="descripcion">Desccripcion: </label>
          <input type="text" value="<?php echo $registro['descripcion']; ?>" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" >
       <label for="imagen">Imagen: </label>
        <img height="200px" src="./<?php echo $row['ruta_imagen']; ?>">
        <label for="imagen">Cambiar Imagen</label>
        <img height="200px" src="./<?php echo $row['ruta_imagen']; ?>">
            <input type="file" value="<?php echo $registro['ruta_imagen']; ?>" name="imagen" id="imagen" >
            <input type="hidden" name="cve_imagen" value="<?php echo $registro['cve_imagen']; ?>">
        <input type="submit"  value=" Actualizar "> 
           <?php } ?>
      </form>

    </div>
<?php
mysqli_close($conexion);
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Una vez que coloco

```html
 <?php while($registro=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
```

el formulario desaparece
Y este es para que se actualice

```html
<?php
include('conexion.php');
if(isset($_GET['cve_imagen'])){
    $cve_imagen=$_GET['cve_imagen'];
}
  if(isset($_GET['nombre'])){
    $nombre=$_GET['nombre'];
  }
  if(isset($_GET['descripcion'])){
    $descripcion=$_GET['descripcion'];
  }
   if(isset($_GET['ruta_imagen'])){
    $ruta_imagen=$_GET['ruta_imagen'];
  
  
$sql = "UPDATE imagenes SET nombre = '$nombre', descripcion='$descripcion', ruta_imagen='$ruta_imagen' WHERE cve_imagen='$cve_imagen' ";
mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert ('Los datos se actualizaron exitosamente');
window.location='agregaruser.php';
</script>";
 }else {
     echo"<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert ('Error al actualizar los datos');
window.location='agregaruser.php';
</script>";
  
 }

 ?>
    <?php
      $conexion->close();
     ?>
```

No se si actualizara porque el formulario no aparece, no puedo efectuar la actualizacioón.
Gracias

Comment: buenas compadre, en el unlink("C:/\\wamp64/\\www/\\Proyecto") te falta agregar el nombre del archivo.. estas colocando solo la ruta al directorio base de tu proyecto

Comment: respecto al update, tienes el codigo dentro de la condicion if(isset($_GET['ruta_imagen'])){ ... entonces, solo si ruta_imagen esta seteado se va a ejecutar... dale una mirada a tus if..

Comment: @varTop gracias compa, en el update ya me di cuenta del error

Comment: @varTob en el php de borrar eso pense en esxt

Comment: @varTob en el php de borrar eso pense en extraer la ruta del archivo con un "SELECT ruta_imagen FROM imagenes where cve_imagen='$cve_imagen'"; pero despues no se que hacer

Comment: antes de llamar al DELETE tienes que hacer el select para traer los datos de la imagen.. necesitas almacenar en una variable la ruta que guardas de la imagen para concatenarla en el unlink.. ej. unlink("C:/\\wamp64/\\www/\\Proyecto/\\".$ruta_imagen);

Comment: sii eso hice y ya me salio, gracias. :v